# How to disable swagger validation in net core

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I'm looking for a way to disable the swagger validation feature when using Swashbuckle for a net core web api project. More precisely how can I set the ValidatorUrl to null.

Comment: Can you give more information on which Nuget of Swashbuckle you are using ? The new nugets for .net-core (Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen, Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi) don't seem to have the validation feature.

Comment: I'm using the "Swashbuckle": "6.0.0-rc1-final" package

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems to me that the validation feature has not been ported. So it might not be necessary to set ValidatorUrl to null ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How disable the swagger validator when using Swashbuckle for a net core web api project. Swashbuckle 6.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923109/how-disable-the-swagger-validator-when-using-swashbuckle-for-a-net-core-web-api)

Comment: I answered that question a week ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44830406/1466583 it is disabled by default on `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 1.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is not disabled by default. I am running Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v1.1.0 and .net core 2.0. I have tried the following which DOESN'T WORK

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MY API");
            c.EnabledValidator(null);
        });
```

The only solution that I have found is to modify their swagger-ui.js file. I don't like this solution but it works.

Around line 198 you will see the following:

```
    return "    <span style=\"float:right\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=\""
    + ((stack1 = (helpers.escape || (depth0 && depth0.escape) || alias2).call(alias1,(depth0 != null ? depth0.validatorUrl : depth0),{"name":"escape","hash":{},"data":data})) != null ? stack1 : "")
    + "/debug?url="
    + ((stack1 = (helpers.escape || (depth0 && depth0.escape) || alias2).call(alias1,(depth0 != null ? depth0.url : depth0),{"name":"escape","hash":{},"data":data})) != null ? stack1 : "")
    + "\"><img id=\"validator\" src=\""
    + ((stack1 = (helpers.escape || (depth0 && depth0.escape) || alias2).call(alias1,(depth0 != null ? depth0.validatorUrl : depth0),{"name":"escape","hash":{},"data":data})) != null ? stack1 : "")
    + "?url="
    + ((stack1 = (helpers.escape || (depth0 && depth0.escape) || alias2).call(alias1,(depth0 != null ? depth0.url : depth0),{"name":"escape","hash":{},"data":data})) != null ? stack1 : "")
    + "\"></a>\n    </span>\n";
},"compiler":[7,">= 4.0.0"],"main":function(container,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    var stack1, alias1=depth0 != null ? depth0 : {};
```

I removed their anchor tag and it now looks like this:

```
  return "    <span style=\"float:right\"></span>\n";
},"compiler":[7,">= 4.0.0"],"main":function(container,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    var stack1, alias1=depth0 != null ? depth0 : {};
```