# How disable the swagger validator when using Swashbuckle for a net core web api project. Swashbuckle 6.0.0

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

How can I disable the Swagger Schema validator in options for Swashbuckle 6.0.0.  I know it's turned off by default when I run locally but don't see validatorURL option for SwaggerUI()

Answer (score 2):

In Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 2.0.0, you disable validation in the Startup.Configure() method by setting the ValidatorUrl to null:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.ValidatorUrl(null);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that [there is an option](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi/Application/SwaggerUiOptions.cs#L24) on Swagger 6.0.0 to manage Validator.

Didn't try myself, but seems to be pretty explicit on what it does.

Answer (score 1):

from the [github repository](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy/issues/223):

> This level of configuration will be available in the upcoming, stable 6.0.0 release as can be seen in the example website for custom UI config:
>
> https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy/blob/master/test/WebSites/CustomUiConfig/Startup.cs#L30
>
> If you can't wait until then, it's also available with the preview packages now available on MyGet

Answer (score 1):

`Swashbuckle 6.0.0` got renamed to `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 1.0.0`. [See here...](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/223#issuecomment-270946659)

They also switched from `DisableValidator` (.NET Framework) to `EnableValidator` (.NET Core) as you can see in [the docu](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore). So it seems like the Validator is disabled by default in `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 1.0.0`.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.EnabledValidator();
    /* ... */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.EnableSwagger(c =>{ })
      .EnableSwaggerUi(c => { c.DisableValidator(); });
```

Comment: INFO: This won't work with the 6.0.0-beta release of Swashbuckle see [arielorvits' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41241534/1466583)